# Getting content from website with HttpURLConnection (Android API 18)

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

How to get content from website with HttpURLConnection for android APIs 18 and above? The code is working fine for API 23, but inputstream is returning odd values for API 18. This is what I get when I try to read data from URL with API 18:

> TTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store,
>   max-age=0, must-revalidate Pragma: no-cache Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990
>   00:00:00 GMT Date: Wed, 03 Aug 2016 19:01:33 GMTContent-Encoding: gzip
>   P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See
>   https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more
>   info." P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See
>   https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more
>   info." X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
>   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Server: GSE Set-Cookie:
>   NID=83=Nb29w9eQo3Fdx_bQuj6YbdLwSfxjuQT4f1Lcb87IbTXQqdGGh6OyuxxB0XGWxNIiAfMdCePDtDb5P9vMYQvbln7svacSJjFkWnU6-B4AN9vLHHY4RUdL3Xny7zSmE8Lm;Domain=.googleusercontent.com;Path=/;Expires=Thu,
>   02-Feb-2017 19:01:33 GMT;HttpOnly Set-Cookie:
>   NID=83=Z9EmVPVCfKYu4FrAHTVHDPMNM80s23cO6P1VqJAocZHnrQb8QFPKW9BLjQGu5xKOwtqNaT38gTZVJm1zmbT7tVhZAYCQlaSb7dRiSTcqQ71a41cIs4l67RxEkOjXfttC;Domain=.googleusercontent.com;Path=/;Expires=Thu,
>   02-Feb-2017 19:01:33 GMT;HttpOnly Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
>   Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="36,35,34,33,32,31,30"
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked 00000001 00000001 � 00000001 00000001 ��
>   00000001 �� 00000001 �� 00000001 �� �� ��

What would be the reasoning behind this? I can provide the code if needed. I'm fairly new with this and can't find the answer anywhere.

To get response from URL I use

```
private String downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            String contentAsString = convertStreamToString(is);
            return contentAsString;
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

and the method which converts the stream into string

```
private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: and the request url is ...?

Comment: @Olayinka the request url is https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=Na8tXX--5d741fBF3qXgxQ-jgTioUWNF_qRUfaMTI2u2l1ul_HUnJg3AraLc-Zg_-7qR4z385MV_8HoU9qi8lV3nVlpVdzNbOJmA1Yb3SEsKFZqtv3DaNYcMrmhZHmUMWojr9NvTBuBLhyHCd5hHa1ZsYSbt7G4nMhEEDL32U4DxjO7V7yvmJPXJTBuCiTGh3rUPjpYM_V0PJJG7TIaKp8cGSZx_xYuyJMXUeN2rZkXdqYzuG_R6Jippy430I3ogteoSsJwqaprbPnRddBTX1zEidwIB2AQJIW1xFZ9DoEE&lib=MbpKbbfePtAVndrs259dhPT7ROjQYJ8yx

Comment: I convert it to JSONObject later on and it all works perfectly for API 23.

Comment: Can we also see the code where you call the url and extract data

Comment: @Olayinka https://github.com/AndreasLoL/NutikorvAlphaRelease/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/nutikorv/andreas/nutikorvalpha/Objects/ProductsFromURL.java this is the class I use to extract data.

Comment: It doesn't work that way here, you kind of have to add sections of your code connected to the problem to your question.

Comment: Sorry, new to this. Added the code parts to the main post.

Comment: Sorry, where is the part where you encode the url?

Comment: @Olayinka I don't encode the URL, I just pass it to the AsyncTask class and it goes straight to the urlString (The same URL I sent before).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905782/htc-one-bug-parts-of-http-header-appearing-in-urlconnection-inputstream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a similar problem.. The problem is that you are using an HttpUrlConnection on an https request. So all of your data is going to be encrypted. I would recommend using some other HttpRequest library like **http-request** by kevinsawicki: https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request. This will have easy support for getting headers, bodies (Json, XML, Plaintext) and other meta data about the request.

**How to add the maven**
In android studio open up the project viewer and open build.gradle (app)
and add this line in the dependencies list

```
compile 'com.github.kevinsawicki:http-request:6.0'
```

Now open up the (project) build.gradle and make sure under repositories you have this

```
mavenCentral()
```

**Example get request**

```
HttpRequest req = HttpRequest.get("https://google.com");
req.trustAllCerts();
req.trustAllHosts(); //If you are having certificate problems
int code = req.code();
String body = req.body();
Log.d("CODE:", String.valueOf(code));
Log.d("BODY:", body);
```

Best regards, David

Answer (score 0):

you might need

```
 in = new InputStreamReader(
                    httpResponseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK ? conn.getInputStream() : conn.getErrorStream(),
                    "UTF-8");
```